# Iterate Multiple std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I've read here and other places that when iterating a std::vector using indexes you should:

```
std::vector <int> x(20,1);
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
  x[i]+=3;
}
```

But what if you are iterating two vectors of different types:

```
std::vector <int> x(20,1);
std::vector <double> y(20,1.0);
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
  x[i]+=3;
  y[i]+=3.0;
}
```

Is it safe to assume that

`std::vector<int>::size_type`

is of the same type as

```
std::vector<double>::size_type
```

?

Would it be safe just to use `std::size_t`?

Comment: If you have been taught about iterating like this, you've been taught wrong. Apart from the `i++` that any decent compiler should optimize to a `++i`, you still call `x.size()` at each turn of the loop, which if it is non-trivial and not inline is wasteful.

Comment: @Matthieu, just a quick and dirty example to illustrate my question.  I should also be using iterators and not doing it by index.

Comment: If you are paranoid you can use `std::common_type<...::size_type, ...::size_type>` , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, for almost any practical purpose, you can just use std::size_t. Though there was (sort of) an intent that different containers could use different types for their sizes, it's still basically guaranteed that (at least for standard containers) size_type is the same as size_t.

Alternatively, you could consider using an algorithm, something like:

```
std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), std::bind2nd(std::plus<int>(), 3));
std::transform(y.begin(), y.end(), y.begin(), std::bind2nd(std::plus<double>(), 3.0));
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, C++ standard doesn't give such guarantees: neither equality of size_types for differently parametrized containers, nor equality to size_t.

Comment: +1. And you were correct, the `std::size_t` guarantee is for allocators only. I thought `std::vector::size_type` had to be equal to `Allocator::size_type`, but apparently not.

Comment: @avakar:The situation is that the standard allocator uses size_t for its size_type, and all known implementations of the standard containers pass the size_type through from their associated allocator. As a result, unless you write your own allocator, it's going to be size_t. From a practical perspective, size_t is essentially always going to work, regardless of what they use as size_type -- e.g. `::operator new` uses size_t for the size of allocation, and essentially all other allocation goes through that (at least by default).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can safely assume that `size_type` is an unsigned nonegative integer. You can't rely on much beyond that. Sure, most containers have a `size_type` which is the same as `size_t` but there are no guarantees.

The SGI documentation and this source http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/ seem to agree on the point.

You may also want to take a look to this solution for your problem: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loop_over_multiple_arrays_simultaneously#C.2B.2B

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that:

```
 for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
```

is something of a council of perfection - are you expecting your vectors to be really gigantic? Personally, I use `unsigned int`, with zero problems.

And now I suppose the downvotes will begin...

Comment: @Neil, love the "council of perfection". I was using unsigned int but reading stuff like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409348/iteration-over-vector-in-c, makes we worry.  Probably un-needed worry.

Comment: @Neil: you'll never live that long -- nobody want to be blamed perfectionist I guess :-D

Comment: @Mark If you are using an unsigned type, you are OK, IMHO. litb's answer to the question you linked is (of course) correct, but you have really got to love typing (in both senses) to use size_type.

Answer (score -1):

You should use iterators instead

```
std::vector <int> x(20,1);
std::vector <double> y(20,1.0);
std::vector<double>::iterator j = y.begin();
for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = x.begin(); i != x.end(); ++i){
  *i +=3;
  *j +=3.0;
  ++j;
}
```

Cause there's no guarantee that u size_type would be the same internal type, anyway, for `std::vector` you could iterate using `unsigned int`

Comment: Why not incrementing `j` in the for control body ? And you too suffer from not using a `max` or `end` variable to check the end of the iteration... stick with `for_each` really ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM, how could you use foreach when you need to iterate across two different vectors? Obviously this example is trite and the loops can be separated, I can't think of a way to do it for x[i] = y[i] + 3