# Simple but new to C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iteration over vector in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409348/iteration-over-vector-in-c)

I'm just trying to figure out how to loop through two vectors and compare data.  Writing a program that will take correct quiz answers and compare to student answers to determine if they are correct. I'm confused with using iterators and how to apply them in this situation. Can anyone help? 
Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us your best non-working attempt?

Comment: Show us partial code, even if it doesn't work, and we'll help you fix it.

Don't show us anything at all, and you get down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> students=get_selections(); //or whatever
std::vector<int> correct=get_cor...

bool is_equal=std::equal(students.begin(), students.end(), correct.begin());
```

Comment: void students()
 {
  for (int i=0;i<NUM_STUDENTS; i++)
  {
   cout<<"\nEnter Student's Names\n";
   cin>>student;
   studentName.push_back(student);
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_QUESTIONS;i++)
  {
   cout<<"\nEnter answer student's answer to question "<<i+1<<"\n";
   cin>>answersS;
   sAnswers.push_back(answersS);
  }
  correctAnswers=0;
  
  
   //cout<<"\n"<<cAnswers[i];
   //cout<<"\n"<<sAnswers[i];

   if (iter::cAnswers.begin()==sAnswers[i]);
   {
    correctAnswers++;
  }
   cout<<correctAnswers;
  }

  return;

Comment: @SelliS do you have a vector of correct answers and of what type are the answers ints?

Comment: The answers are char.  cAnswers is correct answers. sAnswers are student answers.

Comment: for (int i=0;i<NUM_QUESTIONS; i++)
  {
equal(sAnswers.begin(), sAnswers.end(), cAnswers.begin()); 
   correctAnswers++;

Comment: Why not `bool is_equal = (students == correct);`?