# Vector C++ Sorting and Printing

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, cout

Does a vector return false if the element does not exist? I am trying to iterate through a vector and print out each sorted element as long as they exist. Here's a snippet of the code I am working with:

```
typedef struct { 
    string Name;
    map<string,string> Numbers;
} Person

bool ComparebyAlpha(const Person &person1, const Person &person2) {
     return person1.Name < person2.Name;
}

voic print_Contacts(vector <Person> Contacts) {
    sort(Contacts.begin(), Contacts.end(), ComparebyAlpha);
    int num = 0;
    while (Contacts[num]) {
        cout << Contacts[num].Name;
        num++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `while` loop,

```
while (Contacts[num]) {
    cout << Contacts[num].Name;
    num++;
}
```

you can just use a `for` loop for this

```
for (auto const& person: Contacts)
{
    cout << person.name;
}
```

Or

```
for (auto iter = Contacts.begin(); iter != Contacts.end(); ++iter)
{
    auto person= *iter;
    cout << person.name;
}
```

It is preferable to iterate stl containers using [iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409348/iteration-over-vector-in-c) so you do not index out of range, since they use `begin` and `end`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will be undefined behaviour if you will try to access an element of a vector beyond its size.

You could write simply

```
for ( const Person &person : Contacts ) cout << person.Name << endl;
```