# Access a nested ROS-Message

Tags: c++, ros

I would like to access the second element of ROS-Message `message_a`.

```
# ROS-Message message_a
Header header
message_b[] test
```

ROS-Message 1 contains ROS-Message 2!

```
# ROS-Message message_b
Header header
uint32[] result
```

In my main code I loop with a for-each loop through the message test with the datatyp `message_a`.

```
for ( message_a::Test1 test : message_a.message_b ) {
  uint32_t c = test.result;
}
```

How can I access for example the second element of message_b? I need that because I want to get the result of the second test.

With the for-each loop that you see above, it will loop through all elements of `message_b`. How can I change this for-each loop to a general for-loop? Then I could just loop from 2 to 3...

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want the second result of all tests, the second result of the second test, or all results of the second test?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the range-based (aka for-each) loop to an index based for loop like this which iterates over the second, third, ..., and final result of test 42:

```
std::size_t test_idx      = 42; // Second element of results
std::size_t result_start  = 1; // start from the second result
std::size_t result_end    = your_msg_obj.test.at(test_idx).size(); // run until end of all in the given test

// For loop that iterates over all results in a given test
for ( std::size_t result_idx = result_start; idx < result_end; ++idx ) {
  uint32_t c = your_msg_obj.test.at(test_idx).result.at(result_idx);
  // ... fancy stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ROS documentatation of messages](http://wiki.ros.org/msg) explains that array message fields are generated as `std::vector` in C++. In your case the field `test` is of type `std::vector<message_b>`, `result` of type `std::vector<uint32_t>`.

[C++ vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) can be accessed in serval ways, you can find them in [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409348/iteration-over-stdvector-unsigned-vs-signed-index-variable). In your case simply accessing the items by index should be possible like:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i != your_message_a.test.size(); i++)
{
    //Access the second result item of each test item
    uint32_t c = your_message_a.test[i].result[1];
}
```