# operator << Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading

I am trying to use (learn) the Vectors in C++ and hence I have written this as a simple example. But I getting the error of 'Segmentation fault: core dumped' and I do not where and what the error is. Can someone try to explain me , what it is?

'''

```
struct Vertex {

    int x,y,z;
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vertex& vertex) {

    stream << vertex.x << ", " << vertex.y << vertex.z;
    return stream;
}


int main() {

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vertices.push_back({1,2,3});

    for(int idx = 0; vertices.size(); idx++)
        std::cout << vertices[idx] << std::endl;
}
```

'''

Is ther error because of the operator overloading (<<)? This is just a hunch. Because, When i compile it using g++11, it compiles fine, but when I see the output (using the command ./a.out), the segmentation fault error occurs. Therefore, I am confused.

Comment: Check your for-loops condition.

Comment: look at the [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), it helps a lot to avoid such typos

Comment: How to iterate over a std::vector (different ways): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409348/iteration-over-stdvector-unsigned-vs-signed-index-variable

Comment: *When i compile it using g++11, it compiles fine* -- Compiling fine only means there are no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether the program has logic errors or not, and if you look at your `for` loop carefully, it contains such an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applied 2 modifications:

1. Add include

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
```

2. Fix for-loop condition

```
for(int idx = 0; idx < vertices.size(); idx++)
    std::cout << vertices[idx] << std::endl;
```

Full code should work fine

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Vertex {
    int x,y,z;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vertex& vertex) {
    stream << vertex.x << ", " << vertex.y << ", " << vertex.z;
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vertices.push_back({1,2,3});

    for(int idx = 0; idx < vertices.size(); idx++)
        std::cout << vertices[idx] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the condition for the `for` loop. You wrote `vertices.size()`. Change that to `idx<vertices.size()` and you should be fine.
While you're at it, you might want to change your overloaded operator to include a separator between `y` and `z` as well ;)