# Compilation error C2760 in Visual Studio 2019 but not Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

Using the latest versions of Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio. In both I am trying to use this header-only class to display a vector:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

// Header-only helper class for using strings
class stringHelper
{
public:
    // Constructor / destructor
    stringHelper() {}
    ~stringHelper() {}

    template <class T>
    void PrintVector(std::vector<T> input, const char cSeparator = ' ', bool bNewLine = false)
    {
        // Output an array (std::vector) to the console eg. {1,11,21} => 1 11 21.
        // Example usage: stringHelper::PrintVector<int>(vecOfInts);
        if (input.size() > 0)
        {
            for (std::vector<T>::iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end();)
            {
                std::cout << *it;
                if (++it != input.end())
                    std::cout << cSeparator;
            }

            if (bNewLine)
                std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Visual Studio Code has been configured to use the `cl.exe` compiler from Visual Studio 2019 as follows:

```
{
    // Use MSVC cl.exe (eg. Visual Studio 2019) on Windows
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "cl.exe: Build active file (DEBUG)",
    "command": "cl.exe",
    "args": [
        "/std:c++17",
        "/Zi",
        "/EHsc",
        "/Fe:",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "${file}"
    ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "problemMatcher": [
        "$msCompile"
    ],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    }
}
```

A simple test program might be:

```
#include <vector>
#include "stringHelper.h"

int main()
{
    // Create and print out a vector
    stringHelper helper;
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 17};
    helper.PrintVector<int>(vec); // Expecting: 1 2 17
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio Code, the program compiles and produces the correct result. The Visual Studio project is configured to use C++17 (I tried C++14 as well). When I compile in Visual Studio 2019 Professional, multiple `C2760` compile errors are generated:

```
Error   C2760   syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
```

When I select this line in the `Error List`, the token `it` is highlighted.

Change the internal loop in `PrintVector` to the following, which is subtly different and not what I need. Now everything compiles and works fine in both Visual Studio Code and 2019:

```
for (auto a : input)
{
    std::cout << a << cSeparator;
}
```

The [Microsoft help on C2760](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2760) does not appear to apply. Is this a compiler or VS 2019 bug? Why is this failing in Visual Studio 2019 but not Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Indeed, the code is incorrect, so the bug is actually that it compiled at all.

Comment: Oops! You are quite right, there is an error in `main` (unrelated to the `C2760` compile error). When I copy-pasted the real code into Notepad++ to reduce it to a minimal example, I accidentally deleted a `stringHelper` object. The question is now updated.

Comment: What happens if you change `(std::vector<T>::iterator it` to `auto it`?  Whenever I look at the automatic types generated for iterators they are never as brief as that.

Comment: @Den-Jason: That works! Changing `std::vector<T>::iterator it` to `auto it` in the `for` loop allows it to compile and work . Why? This feels like a VS2019 bug.

Comment: Have submitted this to Microsoft as a (probable) compiler bug directly from `Visual Studio > Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem...` Will update the question if I get a response.

Comment: @AlainD personally I wouldn't trust `std::vector<T>::iterator` to be portable.  I believe different STL libraries implement iterators etc quite differently, _especially_ those provided my Microsoft.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348923/1607937

Comment: Ah, good find, thanks. I'll have to try using the `typename` trick mentioned in that link. Using `auto` feels like a cop-out here, as I would expect  the compiler to handle a named iterator.

Comment: @Den-Jason: Microsoft have responsed and also offered an explanation why the code compiles in `Visual Studio Code`, but not in `Visual Studio 2019`. Your linked question provided good background and was correct. Will answer my own question with these details...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was reported to Microsoft who responded (in under 48 hours!) with an explanation of the underlying issue. This is not a compiler bug, but relates to type deduction when using templates. Read the [full discussion here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/incorrect-c2760-compiler-error-for-template-vector/1305634).

One of the comments provided a useful link to this [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2348923/1607937) with similar details.

#### Executive summary

- `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a [dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) which creates ambiguity issues
- Resolve by specifying that `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a type or use `auto`
  (code examples below)
- Issue is detected by `cl.exe` when using the [/permissive-](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160) option. This is enabled for `Visual Studio 2019` but not (by default) for `Visual Studio Code` or the `Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt`.

To specify as a type:

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = input.begin();
for (; it != input.end();)
```

To use `auto`:

```
for (auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end();)
```

Both solutions have been tested and resolve the compile problem.