# C++ vector::erase problems with OpenCV code

Tags: c++, vector, opencv, erase

I'm having troubles with a part of my OpenCV C++ code:

```
double getVectorMedian( vector<double> values )
{
    size_t size = values.size();
    double median;

    sort(values.begin(), values.end());

    if( size % 2 == 0 )
    {
        median = (values[size / 2 - 1] + values[size / 2]) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        median = values[size / 2];
    }

    return median;
}

void cleanSquares( const vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{
    float tolerance = 0.2;
    size_t size = squares.size();
    vector<double> areas(size);

    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        areas[i] = fabs(contourArea(Mat(squares[i])));
    }

    double medianArea = getVectorMedian(areas);
    double minArea = medianArea * (1 - tolerance);
    double maxArea = medianArea * (1 + tolerance);

    for( unsigned int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if( areas[i] > maxArea || areas[i] < minArea )
        {
            squares.erase(squares.begin() + i); // Here I get the error
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int> > >::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<cv::Point_<int> >*, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int> > > >) const’   main.cpp    /find_notes/src line 154    C/C++ Problem
```

I'm modifying the OpenCV squares.cpp sample program and want to remove all squares that differs too much from the median area of the squares found in the image.

Last in cleanSquares I make a backwards loop and check if each square differs too much and in that case I want to erase that vector from the squares vector. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void cleanSquares( const vector<vector<Point> >& squares )`

`squares` is a const reference, you cannot erase from it. Drop the const, or take by value, according to your final intentions.

I would also recommend using the erase( remove_if( ... ) ) idiom, if you feel comfortable with it.

Comment: Of course, that did the trick. Thanks for the fast answer! :-)

Comment: I also had to change the for loop to for( size_t i = size - 1; i --> 0; ) to get the loop to properly count backwards, explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623263/reverse-iteration-with-an-unsigned-loop-variable

Comment: You wouldn't have had that problem if you used the erase( remove_if( ... ) ) idiom, you wouldn't even had to write a loop. Consider researching it in the future.