# C for loop behaving strangely

Tags: c, for-loop

I have stumbled upon a persistent problem, that doesn't seem to have a rational explanation. The problem seems to lie inside a for loop that goes `for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {etc.}` where `size` is the size of a file stored in a memory buffer and `i` is an unsigned integer. Instead of stopping when `i == 0`, it wraps around - thus resulting in `i = 4294967295` and causing a segmentation fault. Changing the conditional to `i > 0` solves the problem.

However, isn't this kind of peculiar? I must be missing some crucial part of how the for loop operates in C. Doesn't it follow this scheme: initialize, check conditional, increment/decrement, check conditional and so on?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "i" is always greater than 0 as "i" is an unsigned int

Comment: Almost but not quite @RaghuSrikanthReddy.

Comment: @Bart's comment is correct, if a little unspecific.  He means, I am pretty sure, that `i` is always greater than _or equal to_ `0` as `i` is an `unsigned int`, which is nearly but not exactly what Raghu said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An unsigned integer is always `>= 0`.

```
for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {etc.}
```

is an infinite loop if `i` is an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Does that mean when i-- is called with i having value 0 it wraps around itself?

Comment: @ckv when `i` is `0` the value `i - 1` is equal to `UINT_MAX` which is a positive quantity.

Comment: So, that's why it doesn't stop. `i` never becomes negative... I'm so stupid some times! :D thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what happens when `i` approaches `0`.

- `i == 1`: loop executes normally since `i >= 0`. Subtract 1 from `i`. Now `i` contains 0.
- `i == 0`: loop executes normally since `i >= 0`. Subtract 1 from `i`. Because `i` is unsigned, it will wrap around. Thus, `i` now contains 4294967295.
- `i == 4294967295`: loop executes normally since `i >= 0`
- and so on ...

The solution is to either test for something else (such as `i > 0`, like your example) or to increase `i` with every iteration and loop while it is smaller than the size of the file.

Comment: Doesn't it first do the increment/decrement operation and then check? Because at a normal for-loop (i.e. `i++`), when the conditional is `i <= size` the last iteration is for `i == size`, and on exit `i == size + 1`.

Comment: Angel: correct, but this is not relevant for my explanation as a condition-check is always followed by a decrement and a decrement is always followed by a condition-check (if we conveniently forget the loop body).

Comment: Yes, the fact is that I stupidly checked the wrong thing! You're right, it wraps around as it can't become negative and goes infinite... I fixed it, by changing it to: `for (i = size - 1; i < size; i--)`. There will never be a problem in my case, because `size` is always much less than UINT_MAX! :D

Answer (score 1):

According to the C99 standard:

> **6.2.5 Types**
>
> 9) [...] A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,  because
>   a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer
>   type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest
>   value that can be represented by the resulting type.

So, here's what happens in your case:

- `i == 1`, therefore `i--` results in `i == 0`.
- `i == 0`, therefore `i--` results in a wrap-around and `i == UINT_MAX`.
- `i == UINT_MAX`, therefore `i--` results in `i == UINT_MAX - 1` and so on.

One way of fixing your loop is by using the following (https://stackoverflow.com/a/665773/676939):

```
for (i = size; i-- > 0;){
    /* yada yada yada */
}
```

Another way of doing the same is the following (https://stackoverflow.com/a/665758/676939):

```
unsigned fake_i;
for (fake_i = size; fake_i > 0; i--){
    unsigned i = fake_i - 1;
    /* Do something with i */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In unsigned types the most significant bit is not treated as a sign bit.
In your case unsigned int has `4bytes(32 bits)`.

So, when you're decrementing '0', the way it is done is `2's complement` of `1` is added to `0`.
Which is `4294967295` and is the maximum value which is nothing but when all 32 bits are 1.
Hence the result `4294967295`.

While incrementing from the maximum value 4294967295( i.e. when all 32 bits are 1's)
Incrementing this gives all the lower 32 bits with 0's and the `32nd` bit with one. So, there is an overflow to the `32nd` bit which is out of the range of 4bytes for unsigned int.
Hence the value becomes 0.

In general for unsigned types there is a wrap around from `0....MaxValue`.
When incrementing above `MaxValue` you re-enter from `0`.
When decrementing below `0` you re-enter from `MaxValue`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :D The problem has already been solved, though... :)