# Looping over an array, and pushing data to another array

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small script in JavaScript to output an array.
**I want to use the 'years' array, push the data into another array called new_array, and output it via console.log()**.

The only problem is, this is the output!
[image]

```
years = [1996, 1994, 1981, 1976];
new_array = [];


for(i = 0; i <= years.length; i++) {
    popped_element = Object.values(years.pop([i]));
    new_array.push(popped_element);
    console.log(new_array)

}
```

Comment: the undefined is due to the = in <= years.length.

Comment: Why are you using `Object.values`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you really just trying to `Array.reverse()`? That already exists. `years.pop([i])`? What is that supposed to do? `Object.values()` takes an Object as an argument.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The reason I was using it was because before I thought push returned an integer value, and I would need to convert it to an array to represent the value. But I just misused it in my code after toying around for a while!

Comment: You're jumping ahead to writing code when the specifications are unclear. Given the `years` array that your program starts with, what is the output that you want it to produce?

Comment: I wanted to output '[1976, 1981, 1994]' . Sorry for the lack of clarity, my understanding of JS is quite weak since I just started learning today.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and Javascript!  Feel free to check out [these tips](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for getting good answers in the future.

Comment: *Array.prototype.pop* doesn't take any arguments, they're ignored. It always returns the last element of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You're over complicating it, you don't use both a for loop and pop unless your iterating from the end to the beginning**

if you iterate from the beginning while popping the end, you will only get half the array:

```js
 years = [1996, 1994, 1981, 1976];
        new_array = [];


        for(i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
          new_array.push(years.pop());

        }
          console.log(new_array)
```

---

you have two options if you are modifying the original array

**1) Use A While Loop**

keep looping as long as there are still elements in the original array

```js
years = [1996, 1994, 1981, 1976];
    new_array = [];
    
    
while(years.length) {
  new_array.push(years.pop());

}

  console.log(new_array)
```

---

**2) Use a Decreasing For Loop**

iterate from the end of the loop to the beginning

```js
years = [1996, 1994, 1981, 1976];
new_array = [];


for(i = years.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  new_array.push(years.pop());

}
  console.log(new_array)
```

Comment: Reversing the count order on i in the first snippet does not change anything about how the code works, but makes it less standard, more different from the original, and more likely to be a source of a bug in the future.

Comment: it in no way makes it more likely for a bug and reverse loops are not against standard.  you don't modify the array you're woking on while looping through it in increasing order if you're poping off the end. otherwise you would end on the second iteration

Comment: if you're counting iterations going from `0` to length and removing items from the end towards the beginning, your beginning items will never be `pop`ed

Comment: Just save the length before entering the loop. `for(var len = array.length; len; len--)`!

Comment: ibrahim, then you have to do math every iteration. you start at the index before the length, same as in an increasing loop you end at the index before the length

Comment: fair, forgot we were popping, but if your gonna do that, just use a while loop

Comment: This answer need a bit of tidying and it would be perfect.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir what should be tidied?

Comment: Just get rid of the first example of using `for`. Keep just the `while` solution and try to explain more why the third example is wrong (try and use **bold text** as titles).

Comment: 1 UP anyway. Because your answer is the only one that points out that the length property is changing.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks, it blows my mind how many don't realize that, and that one person even tried to correct me

Comment: I didn't realize it either. I know `pop` and `shift` actually reduce the size of the array by 1 every time they're called. But it's hard to actually notice it (never used them inside a loop before). So bravo!

Comment: How could I edit this solution to add only every 500ms a new item? I tried with timeout but somehow did not act as I imagined and only waits for the first item but then pops all together.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you really want to do this?

```
var years = [1996, 1994, 1981, 1976];
var reverse_years = years.slice().reverse(); // years.slice() creates new instance of Array so .reverse() does not affect original Array
console.log(reverse_years);
```

If you don't care if the original Array is affected:

```
var years = [1996, 1994, 1981, 1976];
years.reverse(); console.log(years);
```

Comment: He doesn't need the original array afterwards (because it will be empty because of those `.pop` calls). So why use `.slice`. Just reverse it!

Comment: Sure, if you're not using years again you can simply do `years.reverse();` without even assigning it to anything, since the original Array is affected.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what the intention of the code is, but it has a few issues anyway:

```
for(i = 0; i <= years.length; i++) {
    popped_element = Object.values(years.pop([i]));
```

*Object.values* is experimental and not widely available, so you should not use that. *pop* doesn't take any arguments, so you *pop* the last value of *years* each time. And you're calling *Object.values* on the value returned by *pop*, which is a string that doesn't have any enumerable properties, hence the empty array.

If your intention is to return a copy of the array in reversed order, then copy the array and reverse it:

```js
var years = [1996, 1994, 1981, 1976];

// Copy with slice, reverse with reverse
var reversed = years.slice().reverse();
console.log(reversed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate and assign:

```
years = [1996, 1994, 1981, 1976];
new_array = [];


for(var i=0; i<years.length; i++) {
    new_array.push(years[i]);
    console.log(new_array);
}
```

then arrange elements in revere order (if that's what you wanted):

```
new_array.reverse();
```

and delete the items from years (again, if that's what you wanted):

```
years = [];
```

..or, just use `slice` to copy:

```
new_array = years.slice();
```

Comment: This takes more memory than OP's strategy [once the implementation is corrected].

Comment: @WBT I think you might be under the misconception that `Array.pop()` reduces the memory used by the array. It may, but probably not. Array access is much faster than array mutation too...

Comment: this is actually the most efficient solution if you're just getting all elements

Comment: though instead of looping from the beginning THEN reversing, just iterate from the end and reassign the old array.

Comment: also if your array is referenced elsewhere and you need propagation, you need to do years.splice() instead of reassigning the original variable

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley You're right on all counts.I wasn't sure if the OP really wanted the list in reverse order, which is the major reason I have reverse as a separate operation. In other languages the reverse for-loop is littered with pitfalls (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665745/whats-the-best-way-to-do-a-reverse-for-loop-with-an-unsigned-index), which is another reason I didn't use it ;-)

Comment: @thebjorn C is a whole different ball game though. in javascript you should be just as familiar with them as incrementive loops. there are tons of uses i've came across that make them more efficient than always starting at the beginning

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley I almost never use for-loops on indexes in Javascript anymore. `Array.forEach()`, `Array.map()`, and `Object.keys(obj).map(..)` usually express my intent much clearer.

Comment: i agree with map, but forEach creates it's own scope, and is much less efficient is almost every browser than a simple for loop, i rarely use it

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley I normally transpile from ES6, and forEach with arrow functions makes it much more convenient. It is quite a bit slower (https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/37)

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley—I agree with your sentiments, however Array methods are very much faster in recent browsers than they were to the extent that there is now no significant performance difference with *for* or other types of loop. Even [*DOM NodeLists*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) are getting a *forEach* (`iterable<Node>;`). ;-)

Comment: i guess it's just a force of habit for me at this point. in js if i've gotta iterate,  then for loop it is.

Comment: idk, I'd call 63% slower significant.  you won't see the difference in you day to day apps, but with large scale data its a big thing.  also interestingly enough reverse loops are THE FASTEST because you don't have to check length after every iteration

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley yea, I saw that (the reverse loop speed) too. Interesting.

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley—using `var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen` also avoids checking length. Further, in such simplistic test the code for *add* is likely in–lined in the for loop so the function isn't actually called. If performance is an issue, by all means optimise but it's not common to iterate over arrays of 10,000 items.

Comment: @RobG  i said you won't see it in day to day, but having worked with large scale data, i can assure you there are times that it matters

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to Object.values() in the first line within the loop to solve the empty-array problem:

```
popped_element = years.pop();
```

From [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values.

Your years have no enumerable property values, so it's returning an empty array and adding that empty array as an element in new_array.

The `undefined` at the end is due to the `=` in `<= years.length`.   To fix, make that loop line:

```
for(i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
```

or better yet, store the length before the loop and compare to that instead of accessing years.length on each loop iteration because pop() changes the array length.

Comment: if you use years.pop() while iterating from the beginning, your loop is going to end in the middle.  you're result is going to be `years = [1996, 1994];` new_array=[1976, 1981]`;

Comment: "*Your years have no enumerable property values*" yes it does. The problem is that the OP is calling *Object.values* on `years.pop()`, so effectively `Object.values('1976')`.

Comment: @RobG You seem to be missing a key distinction in English between the singular **set** of years, which has properties, in contrast to the plural **years** themselves (e.g. '1976') which do not.  I'm making the same point you're trying to say, but you misinterpreted that.

Comment: @wbt—I can certainly make that distinction, but it was in your head, not in the prose. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Look at my prose and the use of a plural verb "have," referring to the elements of an array. Look at your comment quoting that and your attempt to contradict it using the singular forms "it" and "does," apparently referring to the array itself. See the mismatch?  ("It" in my next sentence refers to the *function,* `Object.values`.)