# What is the '-->' operator in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, operators, code-formatting, standards-compliance

After reading [Hidden Features and Dark Corners of C++/STL](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/33f173780d58dd20) on `comp.lang.c++.moderated`, I was completely surprised that the following snippet compiled and worked in both Visual Studio 2008 and G++ 4.4. I would assume this is also valid C since it works in GCC as well.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    while (x --> 0) // x goes to 0
    {
        printf("%d ", x);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Where is this defined in the standard, and where has it come from?

Answer (score 9825, accepted):

`-->` is not an operator. It is in fact two separate operators, `--` and `>`.

The code in the condition decrements `x`, while returning `x`'s original (not decremented) value, and then compares the original value with `0` using the `>` operator.

**To better understand, the statement could be written as follows:**

```c
while( (x--) > 0 )
```

Comment: I've seen it jokingly referred to as the "downto" operator (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/i-need-a-program-where-the-user-inputs-an-array-of-doubles-and-the-program-outpu/16232#16232)

Comment: I think you wouldn't really *need* the parentheses around `x--` though it does further enforce the separation. It would probably be enough just to associate tokens more clearly with something like `while (x-- > 0)`.

Comment: The most important reason to use this operator is I believe to avoid the "off-by-one" errors that occur when traversing an array in reverse It's quite easier to use for(int i = n; i-->0;) then for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--). Additionally, for unsigned the second for won't even work, and the first for is one of the easiest ways I've seen it written for unsigned.For example for(size_t i = n; i-->0;)

Answer (score 3964):

Or for something completely different... `x` slides to `0`.

```
while (x --\
            \
             \
              \
               > 0)
     printf("%d ", x);
```

Not so mathematical, but... every picture paints a thousand words...

Answer (score 2610):

That's a very complicated operator, so even [ISO/IEC JTC1 (Joint Technical Committee 1)](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee) placed its description in two different parts of the C++ Standard.

Joking aside, they are two different operators: `--` and `>` described respectively in §5.2.6/2 and §5.9 of the C++03 Standard.

Answer (score 1829):

`x` can go to zero even faster in the opposite direction in C++:

```
int x = 10;

while( 0 <---- x )
{
   printf("%d ", x);
}
```

`8 6 4 2`

You can control speed with an arrow!

```
int x = 100;

while( 0 <-------------------- x )
{
   printf("%d ", x);
}
```

`90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10`

;)

Comment: error: lvalue required as decrement operand

Answer (score 1465):

It's equivalent to

```c
while (x-- > 0)
```

`x--` (post decrement) is equivalent to `x = x-1` (but returning the original value of `x`), so the code transforms to:

```
while(x > 0) {
    x = x-1;
    // logic
}
x--;   // The post decrement done when x <= 0
```

Comment: `x--` is in no way equivalent to `x = x-1`.

Comment: They're semantically equivalent in this case

Comment: `--x` is equivalent to `x = x-1` and `x -=1`. `-1` from me.

Comment: You can say `x--` is equivalent to `(x = x-1) + 1`.

Answer (score 615):

It's

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 10;
    while (x-- > 0) { // x goes to 0
        printf("%d ", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just the space makes the things look funny, `--` decrements and `>` compares.

Answer (score 503):

The usage of `-->` has historical relevance. Decrementing was (and still is in some cases), faster than incrementing on the x86 architecture. Using `-->` suggests that `x` is going to `0`, and appeals to those with mathematical backgrounds.

Comment: Not exactly true. Decrementing and Incrementing take the same amount of time, the benefit of this is that comparison to zero is very fast compared to comparison versus a variable.

This is true for many architectures, not just x86. Anything with a JZ instruction (jump if zero).

Poking around you can find many "for" loops that are written backwards to save cycles on the compare. This is particularly fast on x86 as the act of decrementing the variable set the zero flag appropriately, so you could then branch without having to explicitly compare the variable.

Comment: Well, decrementing toward zero means you only have to compare against 0 per loop iteration, while iterating toward n means comparing with n each iteration.  The former tends to be easier (and on some architectures, is automatically tested after every data register operation).

Comment: This would be better as a footnote in another answer or a comment - it clearly doesn't explain what `-->` means, which is what was asked.

Comment: In x86 ASM, the `LOOP <address>` decreases the `ECX` register, then jumps to `<address>` unless the decrementing of `ECX` resulted in zero.  Decrementing the loop counter towards zero allows the compiler to generate a single `LOOP` instruction, whereas incrementing or counting to other values requires separate INC/DEC/ADD/SUB, compare, and conditional jump instructions.  Modern compilers can often convert other loops to a `counter --> 0` loop if the value of `counter` isn't used in the loop.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment:  `MOV ECX, value`, `@start:`, `<code>`, `LOOP @start` is an x86 ASM equivalent for `counter = value - 1; while (counter --> 0) { <code>; }`.  Note that it will barf if `value` is initially zero, so an extra check is needed pre-loop.

Comment: LOOP was never particularly fast, though.

Answer (score 440):

Utterly geek, but I will be using this:

```
#define as ;while

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    do printf("n is %d\n", n) as ( n --> 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know it looks way cool, but I fear it's deceptive. The reason you're writing C++ instead of Machine Language is b/c you want to convey your intent to the next guy reading your code. This construct violates the principle of least surprise. It is a mental "trip hazard."

Comment: Calling `atoi` makes the code smell immediately.

Comment: @StevePoling Intent is being communicated. When I read this code, I understand that I am being trolled.

Answer (score 377):

One book I read (I don't remember correctly which book) stated: **Compilers try to parse expressions to the biggest token** by using the left right rule.

In this case, the expression:

```cpp
x-->0
```

Parses to biggest tokens:

```
token 1: x
token 2: --
token 3: >
token 4: 0
conclude: x-- > 0
```

**The same rule** applies to this expression:

```cpp
a-----b
```

After parse:

```
token 1: a
token 2: --
token 3: --
token 4: -
token 5: b
conclude: (a--)-- - b
```

Answer (score 302):

This is exactly the same as `while(x--)` for non-negative numbers.

Comment: unless x is negative...

Comment: It really doesn't matter if x starts positive or negative, it will eventually reach zero.

Comment: @jwdonahue it will cause undefined behaviour if `x` starts negative, due to signed integer overflow

Comment: @M.M I couldn't find that in my old C-11 draft.  My recall may not be what it once was, but I am fairly sure that I have relied on integer decrement/increment wrapping around on more than one occasion in the past (DAC wave form generation). Haven't worked in C/C++ much these past 12 years though. Could you point us towards the standards language supporting your claim?

Comment: @jwdonahue see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41280273/1505939 for Standard quotes

Answer (score 265):

Anyway, we have a "goes to" operator now. `"-->"` is easy to be remembered as a direction, and "while x goes to zero" is meaning-straight.

Furthermore, it is a little more efficient than `"for (x = 10; x > 0; x --)"` on some platforms.

Comment: Goes to cant be true always especially when value of x is negative.

Comment: The other version does not do the same thing - with `for (size_t x=10; x-->0; )` the body of the loop is executed with 9,8,..,0 whereas the other version has 10,9,..,1. It's quite tricky to exit a loop down to zero with an unsigned variable otherwise.

Comment: I think this is a little bit misleading... We don't have a literally "goes to" operator, since we need another `++>` to do the incremental work.

Comment: @Josh: actually, overflow gives undefined behavior for `int`, so it could just as easily eat your dog as take `x` to zero if it  starts out negative.

Comment: This is a very important idiom to me for the reason given in the comnmet by @PeteKirkham, as I often need to do decreasing loops over unsigned quantities all the way to `0`. (For comparison, the idiom of omitting tests for zero, such as writing `while (n--)` instead for unsigned `n`, buys you nothing and for me greatly hampers readability.) It also has the pleasant property that you specify _one more_ than the initial index, which is usually what you want (e.g., for a loop over an array you specify its size). I also like `-->` without space, as this makes the idiom easy to recognise.

Comment: ... Actually, I somewhat regret that writing `while(0<--n)` does not do the same thing as writing `while(n-->0)`, and the former is usually not what you want. On the other hand, at least in C++, you can make it descend twice as fast with `while(0<----n)`.

Comment: `x=10; while(x --> 0)` is not the same as `for(x=10; x>0; x--)`... it would on the other hand be the same as `for(x=10-1; x=>0; x--)` .

Comment: Well, also `while(0 <=-- x)`. But this's getting silly(er) :p

Comment: With any level of compiler optimisation, there is **no difference in efficiency.** The assembly output is identical.

Comment: Is `x--` defined behavior if x is unsigned and 0?  Naively, I'd expect `x` to become -1, which doesn't fit in an unsigned and thus be undefined.

Comment: @TroyDaniels unsigned overflow is, in fact, defined behavior.

Answer (score 243):

This code first compares x and 0 and then decrements x. (Also said in the first answer: You're post-decrementing x and then comparing x and 0 with the `>` operator.) See the output of this code:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

We now first compare and then decrement by seeing 0 in the output.

If we want to first decrement and then compare, use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;

    while( --x> 0 ) // x goes to 0
    {
        printf("%d ", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That output is:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 200):

My compiler will print out 9876543210 when I run this code.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x = 10;

    while( x --> 0 ) // x goes to 0
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
}
```

As expected. The `while( x-- > 0 )` actually means `while( x > 0)`. The `x--` post decrements `x`.

```
while( x > 0 ) 
{
    x--;
    std::cout << x;
}
```

is a different way of writing the same thing.

It is nice that the original looks like "while x goes to 0" though.

Comment: The result is only undefined when you're incrementing/decrementing the same variable more than once in the same statement. It doesn't apply to this situation.

Comment: `while( x-- > 0 ) actually means while( x > 0)` - I'm not sure what you were trying to say there, but the way you phrased it implies the `--` has no meaning whatsoever, which is obviously very wrong.

Comment: To drive the point home from @Dukeling, this answer is *not the same* as the original post. In the original post, `x` will be `-1` after it leaves the loop, while in this answer, `x` will be `0`.

Answer (score 168):

There is a space missing between `--` and `>`. `x` is post decremented, that is, decremented after checking the condition `x>0 ?`.

Comment: The space is not missing - C(++) ignores whitespace.

Comment: @H2CO3 This isn't true in general. There are places where white space must be used to separate tokens, e.g. in `#define foo()` versus `#define foo ()`.

Comment: @Jens How about: "The space is not missing - C(++) ignores unnecessary white space."?

Answer (score 156):

`--` is the **decrement** operator and `>` is the **greater-than** operator.

The two operators are applied as a single one like `-->`.

Comment: They're _applied_ as the 2 separate operators they are. They're only _written_ misleadingly to look like "a single one".

Answer (score 151):

It's a combination of two operators. First `--` is for decrementing the value, and `>` is for checking whether the value is greater than the right-hand operand.

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 10;

    while (x-- > 0)
        printf("%d ",x);

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 147):

C and C++ obey the "maximal munch" rule. The same way `a---b` is translated to `(a--) - b`, in your case  `x-->0` translates to `(x--)>0`.

What the rule says essentially is that going left to right, expressions are formed by taking the maximum of characters which will form a valid token.

Comment: Which is what the OP assumed: that "((a)-->)" was the maximal munch. It turns out that the OP's original assumption was incorrect: "-->" is not a maximum valid operator.

Comment: Also known as greedy parsing, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @RoyTinker Greedy *scanning.* The parser has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 136):

Actually, `x` is post-decrementing and with that condition is being checked. It's not `-->`, it's `(x--) > 0`

Note: value of `x` is changed after the condition is checked, because it post-decrementing. Some similar cases can also occur, for example:

```
-->    x-->0
++>    x++>0
-->=   x-->=0
++>=   x++>=0
```

Comment: Except that ++> can hardly be used in a while().  A "goes up to..." operator would be ++<, which doesn't look anywhere as nice.  The operator --> is a happy coincidence.

Comment: @BenLeggiero That could 'work' in the sense of generating code that does something (while infuriating readers who don't like faux-clever code), but the semantics are different, as its use of predecrement means it will execute one fewer iteration. As a contrived example, it would never execute the loop body if `x` started at 1, but `while ( (x--) > 0 )` would. {edit} Eric Lippert covered both in his C# 4 release notes: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/01/some-last-minute-new-c-4-0-features/

Answer (score 76):

Instead of regular arrow operator (-->) you can use armor-piercing arrow operator: --x> (note those sharp barbs on the arrow tip). It adds +1 to armor piercing, so it finishes the loop 1 iteration faster than regular arrow operator. Try it yourself:

```cpp
int x = 10;
while( --x> 0 )
    printf("%d ", x);
```

Comment: Don't forget about the `Extra Long Arrow` operator which moves twice as fast, `x ----> 0`

Comment: and the `Extra Long Armor Piercing Arrow` operator, `----x> 0` for your fast piercing

Answer (score 36):

The simple answer to the original question is that the following code does the same thing (though I am not saying you should do it like this):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    while (x > 0) {
        printf("%d ", x);
        x = x - 1;
    }
}
```

The `x--` is just shorthand for the above, and `>` is just a normal greater-than `operator`.

Comment: This question is not about complications, but about ** Hidden Features and Dark Corners of C++/STL**

Comment: The program here gives different output than original because x here is decremented after printf. That demonstrates well how "simple  answers" are usually Incorrect.

Comment: `The OP's way:      9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0` and `The Garry_G way:  10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1`

Comment: It doesn't do the same thing. Move your `x=x-1` before `printf` then you can say "it does the same thing".

Comment: I agree with your attitude about simple and complicated, however `x=x-1` is definitely more complicated than `x--` (more characters to type, harder to read because people wonder why you're not just using good old `x--`, etc.) Also, C programmers who consider things like side effects in `while` to be overly complicated tend to make me suspicious.

Answer (score 33):

Conventional way we define condition in while loop parenthesis"`()`" and terminating condition inside the braces"`{}`", but this `--` & `>` is a way one defines all at once.
For example:

```
int abc(){
    int a = 5
    while((a--) > 0){ // Decrement and comparison both at once
        // Code
    }
}
```

It says, decrement `a` and run the loop till the time `a` is greater than `0`

Other way it should have been like:

```
int abc() {
    int a = 5;
    while(a > 0) {
        a = a -1 // Decrement inside loop
        // Code
    }
}
```

Both ways, we do the same thing and achieve the same goals.

Comment: This is incorrect. The code in the question does: 'test-write-execute' (test first, write new value, execute the loop), your example is 'test-execute-write'.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Your edit is still wrong. The `a--` after the while shouldn't be there.

Comment: *Both ways, we do the same thing and achieve the same goals.* Not really: both loops iterate 5 times, but the final value of `a` after the loop completes is `-1` in the first case and `0` in the second.

Answer (score 33):

`(x --> 0)` means `(x-- > 0)`.

1. You can use `(x -->)`
   `Output: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0`

> 

2. You can use `(-- x > 0)`  It's mean `(--x > 0)`
   `Output: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`

> 

3. You can use

```
(--\
    \
     x > 0)
```

`Output:  9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`

4. You can use

```
(\
  \
   x --> 0)
```

`Output: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0`

5. You can use

```
(\
  \
   x --> 0
          \
           \
            )
```

`Output: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0`

6. You can use also

```
(
 x 
  --> 
      0
       )
```

`Output: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0`

Likewise, you can try lot of methods to execute this command successfully.

Answer (score 8):

`-->` is not an operator, it is the juxtaposition of `--` (post-decrement) and `>` (greater than comparison).

The loop will look more familiar as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x = 10;
    while (x-- > 0) { // x goes to 0
        printf("%d ", x);
    }
}
```

This loop is a classic idiom to enumerate values between `10` (the excluded upper bound) and `0` the included lower bound, useful to iterate over the elements of an array from the last to the first.

The initial value `10` is the total number of iterations (for example the length of the array), and one plus the first value used inside the loop. The `0` is the last value of `x` inside the loop, hence the comment *x goes to 0*.

Note that the value of `x` after the loop completes is `-1`.

Note also that this loop will operate the **same** way if `x` has an **unsigned type** such as `size_t`, which is a strong advantage over the naive alternative `for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)`.

For this reason, I am actually a fan of this surprising syntax: `while (x --> 0)`. I find this idiom eye-catching and elegant, just like `for (;;)` vs: `while (1)` (which looks confusingly similar to `while (l)`). It also works in other languages whose syntax is inspired by C: C++, Objective-C, java, javascript, C# to name a few.

Answer (score 5):

This `-->` is not an operator at all. We have an operator like `->`, but not like `-->`. It is just a wrong interpretation of `while(x-- >0)` which simply means x has the post decrement operator and this loop will run till it is greater than *zero*.

Another simple way of writing this code would be `while(x--)`. The  *while* loop will stop whenever it gets a false condition and here there is only one case, i.e., `0`. So it will stop when the x value is decremented to *zero*.

Answer (score 5):

Here `--` is the unary post decrement operator.

```
 while (x-- > 0) // x goes to 0
 {
     printf("%d ", x);
 }
```

- In the beginning, the condition will evaluate as
  `(x > 0) // 10 > 0`
- Now because the condition is true, it will go into the loop with a decremented value
  `x-- // x = 9`
- That's why the first printed value is 9
- And so on. In the last loop `x=1`, so the condition is true. As per the unary operator, the value changed to `x = 0` at the time of print.
- Now, `x = 0`, which evaluates the condition `(x > 0 )` as false and the *while* loop exits.

Comment: You forgot to describe the `--` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

That's what you mean.

```
while((x--) > 0)
```

We heard in childhood,

> Stop don't, Let Go (روکو مت، جانے دو)

Where a Comma makes confusion

> Stop, don't let go. (روکو، مت جانے دو)

Same Happens in Programming now, a SPACE makes confusion. :D

Comment: This idea can be abused for distant targets in a bow and arrow style: `while((x --)>          0)`

Comment: That's upto the understanding, whatever seems easy & understandable to a person, it's fine for him/her. Main Goal is to clear the concept and be a successful developer :)

Comment: Of course. And IMHO `while (x --> 0)` is clear and effective. `x` takes all values below the starting one down to and including `0`, which is perfect for a loop enumerating index values for an array for both signed and unsigned types of `x`.