# C++ - How to traverse a list from end to begin?

Tags: c++, list, for-loop, stl

I would like to display my list from the end to the beginning. Like:

```
for (std::list<T>::const_iterator it = list.end(); it != list.begin(); --it)
```

The problem is that it doesn't enter in when it is in the first element (`list.begin()`). How can I do this?

Comment: _it doesn't enter_ because `list.end()` is not inside your list.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [What's the best way to do a backwards loop in C/C#/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/275994/1084416)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use rbegin and rend to get reverse iterators.

```
for (std::list<...>::reverse_iterator it=list.rbegin(); it!=list.rend(); ++it)
```

Comment: and as a bonus, you can use `auto`: `for( auto it=list.rend(); it!=list.rbegn(); ++it ) {...}`

Answer (score 5):

Use reverse iterators:

```
for (std::list<...>::const_reverse_iterator it = l.rbegin(); it != l.rend(); ++it)
```

C++11

```
for (auto it = l.crbegin(); it != l.crend(); ++it)
```

and please don't name your `std::list<T>` instance `list`.

Comment: I believe a reverse iterator should still start with `rbegin` (the last element)... and go to `rend` (the first element), right?   Your answer has it backwards.

Comment: @abelenky Yes that is completely correct. I had a bad cut and paste fail from OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

You want a [reverse iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/). See `rbegin` and `rend`.

Answer (score 0):

**Addition:** Because in `it = list.end();` it gets => pointer [some block of memory] which is understood as "end" (or point where to stop, right or left boundary). So output its content (cout<<*it) you will see memory[block] address. If you declare and use as this:

```
std::list<...>::const_iterator it = list.begin();
  std::list<...>::const_iterator iTail = list.end();
  while(it!=iTail)
  {
      //do smthing
      ++it;
  }
```

either loop will be skipped or you will get some garbage from heap. Its case of const_iterator (didn't read documentation but obviously for "write" protection). 
In case of iterator `std::list<...>::iterator` only `.end()` points to the <strike>last[element]</strike> => [end]. In cases:

> std::list<...>::const_reverse_iterator and std::list<...>::reverse_iterator

iterator shifted automatically to the first elem, depending on `start => end` or `end =>start` you are going to run through list.