# C# / .NET / ASPX : Display last 5 in an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have managed to split a Cookie saved from recent searches into an array of all recent searches held, I now want to only bring out the last 5 searched which will be the most recent in the array

So far I have:

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
        if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
        {
            string userSettings = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value;
            output.Append("<div style='float: right; width: 55%;'> Your recently searched: <ul>");
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] tokens = userSettings.Split(':');
                    int count = 0;
                    int refer = userSettings.Length - 5;
                    foreach (String searchHist in tokens)
                    {
                        if(userSettings.Length > refer)
                        {
                            if (count > 4)
                            {
                                output.Append("<li>" + searchHist + "</li>");
                            }

                            count++;

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    output.Append("<li>" + userSettings + "</li>");
                }
                finally
                {
                    output.Append("</div>");
                    recentSearch.Text = output.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

But this seems to only be skipping the first 5 in the array. Is there an easier way of pulling out the last 5 strings held in an array? Many thanks.

Edit: The array looks like this - `first:second:third:forth:fifth:sixth` so in this case, I need it to bring out: `second third forth` and `fifth`.

Comment: See here for a good way of taking the last `n` elements from an enumerable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453274/using-linq-to-get-the-last-n-elements-of-a-collection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to do a backwards loop in C/C#/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275994/whats-the-best-way-to-do-a-backwards-loop-in-c-c-c)

Comment: thanks, so my code would look like this: `tokens.Skip(Math.Max(0, tokens.Count() - 5));` inside the `try` but where would I `Append` the String held inside the Cookie? @Ric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the last 5 elements out of the array, you can use linq and skip the first `length-5` elements like this:

```
foreach (String searchHist in tokens.Skip(tokens.Length - 5))
{
    if(userSettings.Length > refer)
    {
        output.Append("<li>" + searchHist + "</li>");
    }
}
```

You may need to check if the length is at least 5 before that:

```
int toSkip = tokens.Length - 5;
if (toSkip < 0) toSkip = 0;
foreach (String searchHist in tokens.Skip(toSkip))
   ...
```

Comment: Brilliant, this worked! Thank-you! I'll look into the `Skip` idea for an understanding :)

Comment: @KyleE4K there is no big idea behind. An array is an `IEnumerable` and `Skip` is an extension method that returns a new `IEnumerable` that skips the first _n_ elements of the source `IEnumerable`. [Here is the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this insted of the `foreach` loop if the array always look like this: `first:second:third:forth:fifth:sixth` and you want `second`, `third`, `forth` and `fifth` :

```
for (int i = tokens.Length - 6, i < tokens.Length; i++)
{
    string searchHist = tokens[i];

    if(userSettings.Length > refer)
    {
        output.Append("<li>" + searchHist + "</li>");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just an example of what he wants to achieve. The array does not only contain 5-6 items

Comment: ya was going to say that, it actually has a undefined X amount of things in because the person could of searched 55 things for all I know. But I appreciate the help

Comment: he said: «The array looks like this - first:second:third:forth:fifth:sixth so in this case, I need it to bring out: second third forth and fifth.» - so i did

Comment: @KyleE4K : you said, that in that case you need from second to fifth, what about the sixth?, this aren't the last five - or do you really need last five?