# Most Common Mistake done/seen in C++

Tags: c++, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What C++ pitfalls should I avoid ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373/what-c-pitfalls-should-i-avoid)

What is the most common mistake in C/C++programming that you keep committing or see most of the people do? Being aware of it atleast subconsciously will increase my or anyone's chances of committing it.

Comment: This should be community wiki.

Comment: The most common mistake is thinking that there is such a language as "C/C++" and not understanding that C and C++ are fundamentally different languages.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen - the option to mark a question as CW has been gone for weeks now. You can flag it to moderators if you think it should be CW. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action) meta question and links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What C++ pitfalls should I avoid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373/what-c-pitfalls-should-i-avoid)

Comment: @james: nice one...I just meant in both C and C++, since any mistake in C applies to C++ as well.

Comment: @brian and chris: Thank you. I had not noticed the other topic. Please consider this topic closed. Thanks people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong memory management in all kinds of ways - `new` without `delete`, `delete` on the wrong pointer, unclear ownership of a pointer with resulting memory allocation / deallocation problems etc.

Comment: Using `delete` anywhere other than an RAII container is almost always a major mistake.