# use GCC compiler, if IDE exists?

Tags: gcc, vim, emacs, ide

I wanted to know ,why still use **GCC** and editors (i.e.vim or Emacs ), if there are full ides?

Because I found so many people, and sites still explain programming using **GCC**

I don't want you to feel bored I just want simple answers

Comment: It is not a strange question, it is a non-constructive one. People use what they use, you use what you use and it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I meant (time and productivity) not who prefers what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDEs are just glorified editors (like `emacs` is). The compilation is still done by a command line compiler (very often [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or perhaps [CLANG](http://clang.llvm.org/)). That compilation command is started by the IDE.

And FWIW, it is significant that most free software on Linux coded in C or C++ is using "command line" building utilities (`make`, `gcc`, `autoconf`....). Very few free software are developed using IDEs.

<sup>I strongly suggest looking inside existing free software source code. You'll learn a lot.</sup>

AFAIK, there is no IDE directly compiling C or C++ code. All IDEs are running some command-line oriented compiler, so it is useful to understand how the `gcc` compiler should be invoked (at least to configure your IDE to run `gcc` as needed).

My opinion is opposite to yours, I don't understand why people use IDE (with C or C++). I'm very happy with `emacs` (I build by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> there -bound to `M-x recompile`- and go to the next error site with <kbd>F10</kbd> -bound to `M-x next-error`-. Got that with a couple of lines in my `~/.emacs` file.). And `emacs` already has some auto-completion with <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd>. Occasionally I start the debugger under `emacs` with `M-x gdb` or a shell under `emacs` with `M-x shell`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937638/841108) with more detailed hints.

Comment: so it's mainly for making ides. And it's better to code software in linux using "command line" building utilities ?.

Comment: My opinion is that IDE are useless when coding in C or C++ (unless you count `emacs` as an IDE, which I don't).

Comment: I don't understand your *"so it's mainly for making IDEs"* sentence. What do you mean?

Comment: so you mean that you'll be more productive and do more advanced staff with command line, don't you ?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with many command line utilities. And the decisive advantage of commmand line utilities is that you can combine them (using shell features like pipe, redirection, shell-scripting, shell functions, etc...). And most GCC developers are using command line utilities (with `emacs` or `vim`)

Comment: But why Emacs?? I heard that Vim is more flexible or better than Emacs or I am wrong with that .

Comment: `emacs` vs `vim` is a matter of taste and philosophy. I start one `emacs` (in the morning, till end of work day) and run a lot of things under it. I prefer `emacs` to `vi` (which I sometimes use for sysadmin editing tasks). `emacs` is probably more flexible than `vim` (because you can script `emacs` in Elisp).