# What's the relationship between binutils and gcc?

Tags: c++, linux

As titled, is `binutils` contained in `gcc` for Centos Linux?
If I install gcc rpm package, is there need to install `binutils` also?
What's more, are `gcc` and `g++` both installed by default in Centos?

Comment: Can you do `binutils --version` to check?

Comment: without binutils you won't be able to run any program.

Comment: @rakib: no, you can run programs without `binutils` but you cannot compile them.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Well, whenever we run a program loader loads the required shared libraries (.so files) and that loader program is part of `binutils`, then how can it's possible to run program without binutils? This is what I know so far, am I wrong?

Comment: But the dynamic loader (`/lib/ld-linux.so*`) is provided by the `libc` package, not by `binutils`; you could remove the `binutils` package and still be able to use your Linux system (e.g. the browser or the text processor).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for clarifying. I build Linux from scratch, that time on I build `binutils` as the first package (IIRC) and whenever we install OS `binutils` got installed first and that's where my confusion came from. Moreover I thought dynamic loader is part of `binutils`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `gcc` package probably contains the compiler proper, e.g. files `/usr/bin/gcc` and directory `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/` (which contains the `cc1` executable).

The `/usr/bin/gcc` program starts `cc1` (or `cc1plus` etc...) to compile your source code `*.c`, and also `as` to translate `cc1`-generated assembly code (produced by `cc1`) into object file `*.o`, and at last `ld` to link.

Compile once with `gcc -v` to understand what is happening, it would show the really executed binaries. Notice that `gcc` is only a driving program (starting other executables like `cc1`, `as`, `ld` ...)

The `as` and `ld` programs are provided by `binutils` -which is needed to compile.

So the `binutils` package is a required dependency for the `gcc` package (with many other dependencies, probably including `libc` and `libc-devel`, but if you really want you could use some other *libc* like [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/); the *libc* is generally providing the [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) like `/lib/ld-linux.so*`).

Learn how to use [rpm](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-rpm-using.html) (on Centos, or `dpkg` on Ubuntu & Debian) to query the dependencies between [packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_%28package_management_system%29).

For development you probably want some other packages. Debian has the [build-essential](http://packages.debian.org/jessie/build-essential) virtual package. Probably CentOS has an equivalent. And you'll surely want to use some libraries (and you want the *development* packages for them, e.g. on Debian [libcurl4-gnutls-dev](http://packages.debian.org/jessie/libcurl4-gnutls-dev) to develop with the [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) HTTP client library). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937638/841108) (for Ubuntu and Debian, but you can adapt it for CentOS).

In 2021 you want to use [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) at least, as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and you could decide to code your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (checking *some* coding rules in your C++ code; you also want to *document* your [coding conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions) by writing). Be aware of the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch - does `gdb` is use the `binutils` - meaning, if I wish to be able to use `gdb` on some platform - do I have to have the `binutils` related programs (`ar`, `as`, `nm`, `ld` and the like also installed on the same platfrom?