# Web development environment on Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I am a web developer on window since long time. I usually use WampServer as my local work environment, I would like to know if I could set up such type of environment on Ubuntu that can help me continue my development on Ubuntu.
A step by step guide will be very good for me. 
Thanks.

Comment: actually Linux runs on localhost all the time, you will only need phpmyadmin (for example) and any PHP IDE and you are all set

Comment: Wrong place to ask. For C or C++ see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7937638/841108) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/); also [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) with [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) will teach you a lot.

Comment: Do not hope to run photoshop on ubuntu though...

Comment: But consider [Gimp](http://gimp.org/), [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/); In general get a *new mindset*, don't try to find or mimic on Linux every individual feature or program from Windows. See also [Opa](http://opalang.org/) and [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) for Web programming.

Comment: To Cthulhu, No just need something I could use work like I do with photoshop. All I need is to be able to continue all my projects on Ubuntu no matter the tool I will have to use.
Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good way to get started is [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). It's free and it lets you boot up Linux (any OS, really) without leaving the comfort of Windows. Later when you are more confident, you can try dual-booting.

It takes a lot of learning, and don't be afraid of the command-line. If you rely on GUIs, you will only be using a fraction of the OS.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, though I won't be one of them, some people *will* flame you for calling linux an OS. If you want to learn linux, congrats, ubuntu is a great place to start.

If you really want to get into the nuts and bolts, however, I would reccomend switching once you learn the basics of things like terminal. Secondly, PHP is easily obtainable through `apt-get`, and `phpmyadmin` is excellent. more php-savy people who are better explainers than me have written tutorials for both pieces of software.

MySQL is obtainable in much the same way. I hate to say RTM, but you really do have to read up on `apt-get`, if you're going to get anywhere. LAMP stacks (basically the linux version of wamp) are gotten through installing all this and apache, available as `apache2` in the repos. The standard linux replacements for ps an illustrator are the GIMP and inkskape. The gimp, while getting better is horribly unintuitive, so I would reccommend installing photoshop though PlayOnLinux, an excellent piece of software that simplifies running windows software with something called wine. As for CSS, all you need for that is a good brower.

For editing, I would reccoment gedit for a beginner, and investing you time in learning `vi` or `emacs` at some point, as they are much more powerfull. Finally, I would recoment considering whether linux is right for you. I would reccommend reading [this](http://linux.oneandoneis2.org/LNW.htm) article before deciding. Good Luck!